# UWP: how to log the display events of a PivotItem

Tags: xaml, uwp, pivot, latency, pivotitem

I encounter a **"latency" problem** on a screen that contains a **Pivot** and **5 PivotItems**. These problem only occurs **the first time than the 3rd and the 4th PivotItems are displayed**. When I come back to these PivotItems, or if I select others PivotItems I don't meet the same "latency"...

[image]

I tried to understand where come this problem, so I've added some **events** on the PivotItems: **Loaded**, **Loading** and **GotFocus**. In my logs, I see that Loaded and Loading are well called after the page is displayed, but GotFocus is only called if an item in the PivotItem is focused.

I also use the **SelectedIndex** on the **Pivot**, but this doesn't help  me to understand why I meet latencies with 2 PivotItems...

All the datas of the displayed form are loaded from a **SQLite database** through the **LoadDatas()** method: so when I browse the PivotItems, the datas are already loaded. In my logs, I see that **Loading** or **Loaded** are well called after the loading of the datas in the Constructor:

```
11.07.18.615885 : HomeViewModel - OpenForm()
11.07.18.662764 : DetailsViewModel - Ctor() - start
11.07.18.662764 : DetailsViewModel - LoadDatas() - start
11.07.18.803396 : DetailsViewModel - LoadDatas() - end
11.07.18.803396 : DetailsViewModel - Ctor() - end
11.07.19.053413 : DetailsPage - PivotItem_Loading() - DetailsGeneralPivotItem
11.07.19.053413 : DetailsPage - PivotItem_Loading() - DetailsMachinePivotItem
11.07.19.069042 : DetailsPage - PivotItem_Loading() - DetailsComponentPivotItem
11.07.19.069042 : DetailsPage - PivotItem_Loading() - DetailsFormPartsPivotItem
11.07.19.069042 : DetailsPage - PivotItem_Loading() - DetailsFeedbacksPivotItem
11.07.19.287811 : DetailsPage - PivotItem_Loaded() - DetailsGeneralPivotItem
11.07.19.287811 : DetailsPage - PivotItem_Loaded() - DetailsMachinePivotItem
11.07.19.287811 : DetailsPage - PivotItem_Loaded() - DetailsComponentPivotItem
11.07.19.303432 : DetailsPage - PivotItem_Loaded() - DetailsFormPartsPivotItem
11.07.19.303432 : DetailsPage - PivotItem_Loaded() - DetailsFeedbacksPivotItem
```

The XAML of the 3rd PivotItem, which is concerned by the latency problem, looks like this:

```
<Pivot x:Name="Pivot"
       SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndexPivot, Mode=TwoWay}"
       Opacity="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource ActivityToOpacityConverter}}"
       IsEnabled="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource InvertedBoolConverter}}">

    <!-- 1. General / 2. Machine -->
    ...
    <!-- 3. Component -->
    <PivotItem x:Uid="DetailsComponentPivotItem"
               x:Name="DetailsComponentPivotItem"
               Loaded="PivotItem_Loaded"
               Loading="PivotItem_Loading">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                      VerticalScrollMode="Auto">
            <StackPanel>
                ...
                <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                    ...
                    <!-- Component Order -->
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="4,8,20,0" >
                        <TextBlock x:Uid="DetailsComponentTextBlockComponentOrder" />
                        <AutoSuggestBox x:Uid="DetailsComponentAsbComponentOrder"
                                    Name="DetailsComponentAsbComponentOrder"
                                    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.VComponentOrders}"
                                    DisplayMemberPath="component_order"
                                    TextMemberPath="component_order"
                                    QueryIcon="Find"
                                    Text="{Binding CarForm.component_order, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource StringToNullableIntConverter}}"
                                    TextChanged="asbTextChanged"
                                    QuerySubmitted="asbQuerySubmitted"
                                    SuggestionChosen="asbSuggestionChosen" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <!-- Component Order Type -->
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4,8,20,0" >
                        <TextBlock x:Uid="DetailsComponentTextBlockComponentOrderType" />
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.ComponentOrderType}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComponentOrderType, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    ...                         
                    <!-- Hours -->
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="4,8,20,0" >
                        <TextBlock x:Uid="DetailsComponentTextBlockComponentHours" />
                        <input:SfNumericTextBox FormatString="N0"
                                                Value="{Binding CarForm.component_hour, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                MaximumNumberDecimalDigits="0"
                                                Style="{StaticResource NumericTextBoxStyle}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
                ...                     
                <Grid Margin="4,8,20,0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock x:Uid="DetailsComponentTextBlockComponentPhotos" Grid.Row="0"/>
                    <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.CarForm.images}"
                              IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                              SelectionMode="Single"
                              Grid.Row="1">
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemClick">
                                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PhotoItemClickedCommand}" />
                            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <GridView.FooterTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CommandBar Background="White">
                                    <CommandBar.Content>
                                        <AppBarButton x:Uid="DetailsComponentButtonAddPhoto"
                                                      Icon="Add"
                                                      Command="{Binding AddPhotoCommand}" />
                                    </CommandBar.Content>
                                </CommandBar>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridView.FooterTemplate>
                    </GridView>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </PivotItem>
    <!-- 4. Parts / 5. Feedbacks -->
    ...            
</Pivot>
```

This PivotItem contains a lot of fields:

- **AutoSuggestBox**
- **TextBox**
- **ComboBox**
- **Syncfusion NumericTextBox**
- **GridView** with photos list

I've already tried to migrate from "**{Binding ...}**" to "**{x:Bind ...}**" but I encounter problems with some components: ComboBox, Syncfusion NumericTextBox. So I currently mix these 2 bindings in my page.

I've also tried to **remove the GridView** block, but the latency is always present.

***=> Would you have any explanation? Which events are called at the show of a PivotItem? Is there a way to fix this through XAML? (with "x:DeferLoadStrategy" or another way)***

Comment: I think `x:DeferLoadStrategy` could be a way, but there are [limits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-deferloadstrategy-attribute) when using this attribute. `x:Bind` would also reduce the time. But just from your posted code, I didn't see any size limit in this `PivotItem`, as we known, `ScrollViewer` and `StackPanel` all have infinite size, that will cause the `GridView` lose its `Virtualization`, but you said that latency still happens when you remove your `GridView`.

Comment: More important, I personally think that the problem is the loading of the children components of this `PivotItem`, so the latency here with `PivotItem` loading events not too big relations.

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks @GraceFeng-MSFT. But how to explain the delay between the end of Ctor() and the end of the last PivotItem Loaded event in my logs? There is an half second. And isn't there a way to find the PivotItem event called when it is selected?

Comment: Yes, what I mean is that we need to check the loading/loaded event of the children components of this `PivotItem` to see which control may cause this latency.

Comment: I can do this: but the latency is coming "after" the `Loading/Loaded` events of the `PivotItem`. It occurs only when I display the 3rd `PivotItem`. So if the `Loading/Loaded` events of the children are also called before the change of `PivotItem`, it wouldn't help me...